# Programmatically triggering mouse move event in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, dom-events

I have external html5 canvas that you can paint on some lines using your mouse. I want to programmatically paint something one this canvas e.g. circle but in a form of animation (not painting at once but imitate the way the human would do and paint circle lets say for the duration of 1 sec.

The code on the external is not mine and uses GWT and this way is highly compressed and obfuscated. That's why I thought about triggering a sequence of `mousedown, mousemove, sleep, mousemove, mouseup` events. I know it's possible to trigger mouse down and up event but what about mouse move event at specific location? Ideally using jQuery.

Comment: can you show us your failed attempt?

Comment: unfortunately I'm stuck on how to make mouse move event

Comment: Do you really need to trigger mouse events? What are the reasons not to use lineTo and moveTo to draw programmatically? Tutorial on drawing on canvas - http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-paths/

Comment: as I said the canvas belongs to external code made using GWT. Those paintings on canvas executes some other code as well. Generated GWT code is hard to modify that's why the idea to programmatically triggering events.

Comment: This gist could be useful: https://gist.github.com/3517765

Comment: I already answered a similar question. Try [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55080467/8399492) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you looked at `initMouseEvent` and `dispatchEvent`?

Here is a link https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Document_Object_Model_%28DOM%29/event.initMouseEvent

Comment: This is now deprecated.

Answer (score 3):

The new (non-deprecated) way to do this is with the [`MouseEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/MouseEvent) constructor.

Here's some sample code that you can adapt to your use case:

```
var gestureTimeoutID;
var periodicGesturesTimeoutID;

window.simulateRandomGesture = function (doneCallback) {
    var target = document.querySelector('canvas');

    var rect = target.getBoundingClientRect();

    var simulateMouseEvent = function simulateMouseEvent(type, point) {
        var event = new MouseEvent(type, {
            'view': window,
            'bubbles': true,
            'cancelable': true,
            'clientX': rect.left + point.x,
            'clientY': rect.top + point.y,
            // you can pass any other needed properties here
        });
        target.dispatchEvent(event);
    };

    var t = 0;

    /* Simple circle:
    var getPointAtTime = (t) => {
        return {
            x: 300 + Math.sin(t / 50) * 150,
            y: 300 + Math.cos(t / 50) * 150,
        };
    };
    */

    // More fun:
    var cx = Math.random() * rect.width;
    var cy = Math.random() * rect.height;
    var gestureComponents = [];
    var numberOfComponents = 5;
    for (var i = 0; i < numberOfComponents; i += 1) {
        gestureComponents.push({
            rx: Math.random() * Math.min(rect.width, rect.height) / 2 / numberOfComponents,
            ry: Math.random() * Math.min(rect.width, rect.height) / 2 / numberOfComponents,
            angularFactor: Math.random() * 5 - Math.random(),
            angularOffset: Math.random() * 5 - Math.random()
        });
    }
    var getPointAtTime = function getPointAtTime(t) {
        var point = { x: cx, y: cy };
        for (var i = 0; i < gestureComponents.length; i += 1) {
            var c = gestureComponents[i];
            point.x += Math.sin(Math.PI * 2 * (t / 100 * c.angularFactor + c.angularOffset)) * c.rx;
            point.y += Math.cos(Math.PI * 2 * (t / 100 * c.angularFactor + c.angularOffset)) * c.ry;
        }
        return point;
    };


    simulateMouseEvent('mousedown', getPointAtTime(t));
    var move = function move() {
        t += 1;
        if (t > 50) {
            simulateMouseEvent('mouseup', getPointAtTime(t));
            if (doneCallback) {
                doneCallback();
            }
        } else {
            simulateMouseEvent('mousemove', getPointAtTime(t));
            gestureTimeoutID = setTimeout(move, 10);
        }
    };
    move();
};

window.simulateRandomGesturesPeriodically = function (delayBetweenGestures) {
    delayBetweenGestures = delayBetweenGestures !== undefined ? delayBetweenGestures : 50;

    var waitThenGo = function waitThenGo() {
        periodicGesturesTimeoutID = setTimeout(function () {
            window.simulateRandomGesture(waitThenGo);
        }, delayBetweenGestures);
    };
    window.simulateRandomGesture(waitThenGo);
};

window.stopSimulatingGestures = function () {
    clearTimeout(gestureTimeoutID);
    clearTimeout(periodicGesturesTimeoutID);
};
```

Comment: you should probably not stringify the keys of the second param for new mouseEvent.

Comment: @MathijsSegers It doesn't matter functionally, but yeah, they don't need to be there. I'm sure I copied that part from somewhere and just left it with the quotes.

Comment: `VM2345:55 Uncaught ReferenceError: t is not defined`

Comment: @AlexeySh. Fixed.