# Trigger mousemove event using Jquery or Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas

Hi I know we can trigger click event. but I want to know that can we trigger `mousemove` event without any actual mouse movement by user.

Description :

I want to show a message when user select something. On canvas, my canvas is of full height and width, when user click on a button the canvas shows up. When user do mouse movement he see a message "Click and drag on any part of the web page". This message follows the mouse movement of the user.

What I want to do:

When user click the button he should see the message that "Click and drag on any part of the web page". and message must follow wherever user moves the mouse.

Problem :

User is not able to see the message after click until he/she moves his mouse.

Code:

```
      function activateCanvas() {
           var documentWidth = jQ(document).width(),
           documentHeight = jQ(document).height();
        
                 jQ('body').prepend('<canvas id="uxa-canvas-container" width="' + documentWidth + '" height="' + documentHeight + '" ></canvas><form method="post" id="uxa-annotations-container"></form>');

    canvas = new UXAFeedback.Canvas('uxa-canvas-container', {
        containerClass: 'uxa-canvas-container',
        selection: false,
        defaultCursor: 'crosshair'
    });


  jQ(function() {
        var canvas = jQ('.upper-canvas').get(0);
        var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
        var x,y;

        var tooltipDraw = function(e) {

            ctx.save();
            ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            ctx.restore();

            x = e.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
            y = e.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
            var str = 'Click and drag on any part of the webpage.';

            ctx.fillStyle = '#ddd';
            ctx.fillRect(x + 10, y - 60, 500, 40);
            ctx.fillStyle = 'rgb(12, 106, 185)';
            ctx.font = 'bold 24px verdana';
            ctx.fillText(str, x + 20, y - 30, 480);

        };

        canvas.addEventListener('onfocus',tooltipDraw,0);
        canvas.addEventListener('mousemove',tooltipDraw,0);

        canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
            canvas.removeEventListener('mousemove', tooltipDraw, false);
            ctx.save();
            ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0);
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
            ctx.restore();
        }, false);



       });
  }

        jQ('body').on('click', '.mood_img_div', function() {
    // alert("soemthing");
      toggleOverlay();
       activateCanvas();
       });
```

I have made a function which is called after click but the message is not visible. Is there any way to call it for the first time with message and show is everytime when user uses mouse.

**I have replaced jQuery with jQ because I am making my own plugin(this is not causing the problem)**

Comment: What is `jQUxarmy`? Is that supposed to be `jQuery`?

Comment: what is this `jQUxarmy`? is it an edited version of jQuery?

Comment: I have replaced jquery with my own variable jQUxarmy .

Comment: why don't you just add a call to `tooltipDraw` at the end of your click handler? You just have to pass the click event has argument and you're done no?

Comment: actually the function is called when click is made but the text is drawn only when user moves the mouse. I am looking for any so that it the text would be made visible just after user clicks. So i need to generate the mousemove event @Kaiido

Comment: @pawankumar, you are probably not passing the event to this call, so x and y are NaN. But I don't find in your code block where is this call made.

Comment: Oh and were you expecting that the onfocus would do it ? canvasElement is not focusable per se. Only its hidden content can have focus and only through keyboard navigation, not through click events, and the focus event won't bubble to the canvas anyway.

Comment: then what should I do. I have passed it like this canvas.dispatchEvent(new Event('mousemove'),tooltipDraw); tootltioDraw is the function which is responsible for drawing the text. on the canvas.

Comment: Check my answer, you just need to gather the **click** event and add as an argument to tooltipDraw call : `canvas.onclick = function(evt){ do_something_else(); tooltipDraw(evt);}`

Answer (score 28):

A good native approach is to use [`dispatchEvent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) method on EventTarget.

It dispatches an **Event** at the specified **EventTarget**, invoking the affected **EventListeners** in the appropriate order. The normal event processing rules (including the capturing and optional bubbling phase) also apply to events dispatched manually with `dispatchEvent()`.

Try

```
// 1. Add an event listener first
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', tooltipDraw, 0);

// 2. Trigger this event wherever you wish
canvas.dispatchEvent(new Event('mousemove'));
```

In your case it should trigger mousemove event on canvas element.

([Triggering events in vanilla JavaScript](http://www.2ality.com/2013/06/triggering-events.html) article can be also useful):

```
var elem = document.getElementById('elementId');

elem.addEventListenter('mousemove', function() {
  // Mousemove event callback
}, 0);

var event = new Event('mousemove');  // (*)
elem.dispatchEvent(event);

// Line (*) is equivalent to:
var event = new Event(
    'mousemove',
    { bubbles: false, cancelable: false });
```

---

**jQuery:**

Try this with jQuery `trigger` method:

```
 $('body').bind('mousemove',function(e){   
    // Mousemove event triggered!
});
$(function(){
    $('body').trigger('mousemove');
});
```

OR (if you need triggering with coords)

```
event = $.Event('mousemove');

// coordinates
event.pageX = 100;
event.pageY = 100; 

// trigger event
$(document).trigger(event);
```

OR
Try using [.mousemove()](https://api.jquery.com/mousemove/) jQuery method

Comment: Also initMouseEvent

Comment: The `initMouseEvent` feature was **DEPRECATED** and has been removed from the Web standards. https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/MouseEvent/initMouseEvent

Comment: I tried the last method and it didnt worked before posting question here. I want to trigger event without user interaction.

Comment: All of them dispatch event without user interaction. Try `canvas.dispatchEvent(new Event('mousemove'));`, in your case it should trigger mousemove event on canvas element.

Comment: I have tried using canvas.dispatchEvent(new Event('mousemove'),tooltipDraw,0); but it didn't worked.

Comment: Of course it didn't. **You do not read my answer and links.** First you should add an `eventListenter` with a callback and only then trigger it with `dispatchEvent`. Updated the answer code, see it above.
Please read the links I left above about dispatchEvent method (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent) and how DOM events work.

Comment: I can't use JQuery(since I am creating a library and it is in an external script and other people may not have installed JQuery) and the ```disptachEvent()``` doesn't work(I am using document instead of canvas), is there any other way?

Answer (score 9):

```
let coordX = 0; // Moving from the left side of the screen
let coordY = window.innerHeight / 2; // Moving in the center

function move() {
    // Move step = 20 pixels
    coordX += 20;
    // Create new mouse event
    let ev = new MouseEvent("mousemove", {
        view: window,
        bubbles: true,
        cancelable: true,
        clientX: coordX,
        clientY: coordY
    });

    // Send event
    document.querySelector('Put your element here!').dispatchEvent(ev);
    // If the current position of the fake "mouse" is less than the width of the screen - let's move
    if (coordX < window.innerWidth) {
        setTimeout(() => {
            move();
        }, 10);
    }
}

// Starting to move
move();
```

Comment: I absolutely love this solution. Thanks for this.

Answer (score 1):

Albeit it is probably possible to mimic such an event as shown in Andrii Verbytskyi's answer, most of the time, when you want to do it, it is because of an ["X-Y problem"](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/XyProblem).

If we take OP's case for instance, here we absolutely don't need to trigger this mousemove event.

**Pseudo-code of current implementation :**

```
function mousemoveHandler(evt){
    do_something_with(evt.pageX, e.pageY);
}
element.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemoveHandler)

function clickHandler(evt){
    do_something_else();
}
element.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
```

And what we want is to also call `do_something_with` in the click handler.

So OP spends some time to find a way to trigger a fake mousemove, spends another amount of time trying to implement it, while all that is needed is to add a call to `do_something_with` in `clickHandler`.

Both mousemove and click events have these `pageX` and `pageY` properties, so the event can be passed has is, but in other case, we could also just want to pass it with a fake object containing required properties.

```
function mousemoveHandler(evt){
    do_something_with(evt.pageX, evt.pageY);
}
element.addEventListener('mousemove', mousemoveHandler)

function clickHandler(evt){
    do_something_else();
    do_something_with(evt.pageX, evt.pageY);
}
element.addEventListener('click', clickHandler);
// here we won't have pageX nor pageY properties
function keydownHandler(evt){
    do_something_else();
    // create a fake object, which doesn't need to be an Event
    var fake_evt = {pageX: someValue, pageY: someValue};
    do_something_with(fake_evt.pageX, fake_evt.pageY);
}
element.addEventListener('keydown', keydownHandler);
```

**Note** : you are mixing `jQuery.on` and `element.addEventListener`, so you might need to pass the originalEvent property of the jQuery event object.