# Javascript simulate mouse move event on canvas

Tags: javascript

Hey I'm wondering if someone could help me with my simulate mouse move event I been trying to simulate a mouse move from the window inner width and height to an object x,y position on a canvas. I can get the object position but when I try simulate the mouse move from the window center to the object it's way off the object position any ideas why this happen?

```
function moveMouse(x, y) {
  var centerX = window.innerWidth / 2;
  var centerY = window.innerHeight / 2;
  document.dispatchEvent(new MouseEvent("mousemove", {
    clientX: centerX + x,
    clientY: centerY + y
  }));
}

function getObj() { 
  var obj = Game.currentGame.world.localPlayer.entity; 
  return obj
}

var obj = getObj();
var objPosition = {
  x: obj.fromTick.position.x,
  y: obj.fromTick.position.y
}

console.log(objPosition) // works 

moveMouse(objPosition.x, objPosition.y)
```

sorry mebad english

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Trigger mousemove event using Jquery or Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41143263/trigger-mousemove-event-using-jquery-or-javascript)

Comment: Are `objPosition.x, objPosition.y` coordinates relative to the canvas top-left corner?

Answer (score 0):

If `objPosition.x, objPosition.y` are coordinates of the object on the canvas relative to the top-left corner of the canvas, then your `mouseMove()` function should add `x, y` to the coordinates of the top-left corner of the canvas, rather than the coordinates of the center of the window.

You can acquire coordinates of the canvas with [canvas.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect).

Alternatively if `objPosition.x, objPosition.y` are absolute coordinates of the object relative to the top-left corner of the window, then simply `mouseMove()` directly to them.